# l10n Translations does not show in settings

Tags: drupal, localisation, translation

I'm using Civicrm v4.7.19 on Drupal,

for using another language (like ES/DE) I've been creating directory:
/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/l10n

And the "mo" files placed in these addresses [both for testing]:
/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/l10n/es_ES/civicrm.mo
/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/l10n/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/civicrm.mo

But the Localization settings page don't show the languages.

[image: Directory]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Can you check:

- Go to Administer > System Settings > Option Groups
- Then search for "Languages" and click on its "Options" link.
- Double-check that the language is enabled.

Otherwise, it might be a file permission issue: can you check to make sure that the web server has permission to read the l10n directory and files?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've been enabled Persian language (and other languages like Spanish) before, but it doesn't shows any language except English

Comment: I opened this issue to track the bug: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20803